How do I run a macro by clicking the values in a List Box form control without adversely affecting its scrollbar functionality?
I'm having a problem with a List Box form control that I placed on a worksheet. The List Box has over 100 values listed in it (the total number of values dynamically fluctuates, which I can elaborate on if necessary, but I didn't think the reasoning behind this was really relevant to the problem I'm having). I wanted to run a macro when any of the values listed in the List Box are clicked by a user, so I stored the macro as a public sub in the module for the worksheet on which the List Box is placed (I can elaborate on what the macro is supposed to do, but again, I didn't think this was relevant to the problem) and then assigned the macro to the List Box form control by right clicking it, clicking "Assign Macro...", choosing the macro from the list, and clicking the "OK" button.
So here's where the problem comes in: the macro does run whenever one of the values in the List Box is clicked, however, for whatever reason, it also runs every single time that any part of the List Box's righthand scrollbar is clicked — whether it's the scroll up button, the scroll down button, the scrollbar itself, or the empty space between the scrollbar and these buttons — which is unacceptable.
The problem is compounded by the over 100 values contained in the List Box, with the potential for even more values to be listed over time; the VBA code in the macro is not very long or complex, however it still results in a noticeable pause of a couple seconds and temporarily prevents the user from clicking anything else each time that it's run, which I don't mind when a value is clicked, but I can't have that happen each time a user tries to scroll up or down through the List Box's literally hundreds of values, as it renders the List Box essentially unusable.
Normally, I would use a List Box ActiveX control instead of a List Box form control (not sure if this would avoid this particular problem), but for the purposes of the workbook (at least the way I've designed it currently), I need the values in the List Box to be able to dynamically fluctuate as mentioned above, and when trying out this functionality, I could find a way to make it work only with the form control and not with the ActiveX control.
Am I doing something wrong? And more importantly, does anyone know of a way to fix this? I could be mistaken, but I can't imagine that Microsoft would implement the ability to run a macro by clicking on the values in a List Box form control without first testing for and/or debugging what I would consider to be an obvious issue with said implementation. So I have to believe either that I'm doing something wrong or that this is just an inherent issue with this form control.

Yes you need to use the ActiveX version. Assigning a macro to a Form Control object just assigns it in the background to the click event as you found out. There is no way to change that. That functionality is often only used with the button control.
With the ActiveX control you can specify which events you want to react to, like in your case, the Change event. You can dynamically change the contents by updating the ListFillRange property or by adding/removing listitems manually.
